# TTURLAction applyAnimated doesn't animate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I currently use the Three20 framework for a project. But the following doesn't work as aspected. It doesn't preform any animation, it simply pushes the screen directly on top.

```
[[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:[[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"lp://miniapp/1"] applyAnimated:YES]];
```

I tested in the simulator and on the device.

Answer (score 0):

```
TTURLAction *urlAction=[[[TTURLAction alloc] initWithURLPath:strTTURL] autorelease];
urlAction.animated=YES;
[[TTNavigator navigator]openURLAction:urlAction];
```